# bgStretcher jQuery plugin adds space above bg image only on certain aspect ratios - possibly quick fix

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

Please see here: http://www.dearearth.net/
The jQuery plugin page with demo: http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html

The issue appears in **Safari** and **Chrome** only.

**To replicate the issue:** While in either browser, try to dynamically resize the window size, and notice how under certain aspect ratios, the background is pushed down about 20px or so, revealing the bg color..

Any ideas why? This does not happen in the demo...:/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ktash over at doctype.com for the solution:

```
.bgstretcher, .bgstretcher ul, .bgstretcher li {
list-style: none;
```

}